# Getting so much time delay in WCF webservice response

Tags: c#, wcf, https, webservice-client

I have a WCF webservice which sends(returns) DataTable to the client. Now i have 47,000 records in datatable. At the first call its taking too much time to get the data.

i had set **Generate serialization assembly** to '**on**' and tried **useDefaultWebProxy="false"** in config file but problem couldn't solve.

here is my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_I123Services" closeTimeout="00:30:00"
                openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false"        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="500000000"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="false"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2000000"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2000000" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:30:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://123.com/123services.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_I123Services" contract="123Services.I123Services"
            name="WSHttpBinding_I123Services" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

can anyone help me to find me a solution for this.
thank you.

Comment: Not sure if it a config issue? Is your query timing out? Check to see how long it takes for your backend to generate the response

Comment: Don't have any timeout issue. There is 26 seconds of delay now.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d6e234d3-942f-4e9d-8470-32618d3f3212/maxbufferpoolsize-vs-maxbuffersize maybe of help

Comment: 1. Don't return DataTable from a web service! http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx

Comment: @hugh thank you for the advice. I have changed the DataTable to byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it by the following,

Data return as byte array instead of DataTable with compression. just used the below section.

```
 public byte[] ToByteArray(object o)
    {
        if (o == null)
            return new byte[0];

        using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(outStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(stream, o);
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    stream.CopyTo(zipStream);
                    zipStream.Close();
                    return outStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }



  public object ToObject(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        if (byteArray.Length == 0)
            return null;

        using (MemoryStream decomStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray), ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (GZipStream hgs = new GZipStream(decomStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                hgs.CopyTo(ms);
                decomStream.Close();
                hgs.Close();
                ms.Position = 0;
                return new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(ms);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it may helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, by returning a database from a service operation, you'll definitely be bulking out the response size. See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx.

Secondly, what do you expect, returning 47K rows of data across the network? That's alot of serialization overhead. I'm surprised your call is only taking 26 seconds to return. Why do you need to load 47K rows of data into your client?

It sounds like you have put a service boundary in between two things which should really be running in-process with each other. In memory, this much data would take milliseconds to return.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.Will it reduce the time delay by compressing(GZIP) the DataTable into byte array ?